# How can I select multiple users

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 mb-4">
  <div className='floating-label'>
    <select className='floating-select' onChange={formik.handleChange} name="select_employee" placeholder=" " onSubmit={setSelectedOption} closeMenuOnSelect={false} noOptionsMessage={()=> "No Employee Available"} required isMulti isSearchable // name="select_employee" // options={optionData} // className="basic-multi-select" // classNamePrefix="select" // placeholder=" " // onSubmit={setSelectedOption} // closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      // noOptionsMessage={() => "No Employee Available"} styles={{ placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, // color: "#027581", }), control: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, backgroundColor: "transparent", borderStyle: "none", borderWidth: "none",
      borderRadius: '0px', borderColor:'none', boxShadow: 'none', borderBottom: '1px solid #757575', transition: 'background-color 0.2s ease-in-out', '&:hover': { backgroundColor: "none", }, }), multiValueRemove: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, color:
      "#000", }), multiValueGeneric: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, color: "#fff", }), menuList: (baseStyles) => ({ ...baseStyles, backgroundColor: "#f3f3f9", }), option: (baseStyles, state) => ({ ...baseStyles, color: state.isFocused ? '#fff' : '#000',
      backgroundColor: state.isFocused ? '#1e90ff' : '#f3f3f9' }) } } >
      <option value=''> </option>
      {optionData.map((selectEmployee, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={selectEmployee.value}>{selectEmployee.label} </option>
      ))}</select>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <label>Select Employee</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

best solution and simple learning

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

When using  you should be able to select multiple options by holding CTRL and clicking.

Comment: no it's not working